# Getting the 30 mins max sum of Column B per day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have the first column with dates at different time stamps. for the second column, i have the data.  Let First column be A, Second column be B. i need to get the the sum of the data which is the maximum sum  within 30 mins duration in a day.

So for example, for the data below,

```
dateTimeRead(YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss)   rain_value(mm)  air_pressure(hPa)
1/2/2015 0:00                       0               941.5675
1/2/2015 0:15                       0               941.4625
1/2/2015 0:30                       0               941.3
1/2/2015 0:45                       0.1               941.2725
1/2/2015 1:00                       0.2             941.12
1/2/2015 1:15                       0.3               940.8625
1/2/2015 1:30                       0.6               940.7575
1/2/2015 1:45                       0.2               940.6075
1/2/2015 2:00                       0               940.545
1/2/2015 2:15                       0               940.27
1/2/2015 2:30                       0               940.2125
1/2/2015 16:15                      0               940.625
1/2/2015 16:30                      0               940.69
1/2/2015 16:45                      0               940.6175
1/2/2015 17:00                      0               940.635
1/2/2015 19:00                      0               941.9975
1/2/2015 20:45                      0               942.7925
1/2/2015 21:00                      0               942.745
1/2/2015 21:15                      0               942.6325
1/2/2015 21:30                      0               942.735
1/2/2015 21:45                      0               942.765
1/2/2015 22:00                      0               941.6
1/3/2015 2:15                        0.1              
1/3/2015 2:30                       0.2               941.1275
1/3/2015 2:45                       0.1               941.125
1/3/2015 3:00                       0.1             940.955
1/3/2015 3:15                       0               941.035
```

the desired output would be

```
Date            Max Sum
1/2/2015      1.1
1/3/2015        0.4 
and so On
```

Comment: Please explain in detail with sample input and output

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input and desired output. Also show the current output of what you've tried so far, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. Also, you didn't even indicate what a4,a5,a6,... are.

Comment: You have gaps in your data, e.g. 1/2/2015 2:30 is followed by 1/2/2105 16:15. How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track the 30-minute interval sums in a helper column, then using an array formula to calculate the max per day.

For example, let's suppose your data above is in columns A-C. (But we ignore the data in C and focus on column B as you have done in your example.) In `$D$1`, let's put your desired interval, `0:30`. In column E, we'll keep track of, for each time in column A, what the sum of `rain_value` was for the last 30-minute window. To calculate this, you could paste the following formula in E2 and copy down the column (adjusting if you want `>` instead of `>=`, for example):

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&A2,A:A,">="&A2-$D$1)
// assumes the time interval is in $D$1
```

Now you have a column of data that includes the windows over which you want to take the max. One way to do this is by using the `MAX` formula as an array formula. First, create a new column F which just extracts the date part of the datetime in column A. You can do this just by putting `=INT(A2)` in cell F2 and copying down, for example.

Then, create a column G just for your dates (`1/2/2015` and `1/3/2015` in your example). In column H, calculate the following array formula* in H2 and copy down to get the max of column E:

```
{=MAX(IF(F:F=G2,E:E))}
```

This will get the max per date.

*If you don't know how to execute array formulas, basically just type the formula `=MAX(IF(F:F=G2,E:E))` into H2, but then instead of typing Enter, type Ctrl-Shift-Enter on Windows (or Cmd-Enter on a Mac). There are ways to do this last part without array formulas too, with clever use of `SUMPRODUCT` or `INDEX`.